# How to have a route in ASP.NET MVC with a file extension that would be blocked by request filtering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a route that basically looks like this:

```
Foo/{id}/Files/{*path}
```

I want it to match a URL such as:

```
http://mysite/Foo/Bar/Files/Baz.cs
```

However, I get an HTTP 404.7 error that says "The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension."  I can remove the file extension from request filtering by modifying web.config, but I don't want my source code to be viewable.  How should I set this up?

Comment: i think you should add it to ignore list look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186008/asp-net-mvc-ignoreroute-method-doesnt-work-correctly-when-url-starts-with-vie

Answer (score 1):

The only way you might have possibility to get it working is through relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping setting in ASP.NET 4.0. You can read more here:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

Comment: Edited web.config, then what?

Answer (score 0):

If the paths to the files don't match with the urls you want to have than you can do the following:

1. mark the folder where you keep your source files as denied for everyone in the web.config (example for the /SourceCode dir)
2. allow the .cs extension in the request filtering module

Comment: Can you show how to modify web.config to keep the source files denied for everyone?